# Will Immigration be done at first point in Schengen or at end destination?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, europe, eu, amsterdam, munich

If a flight is taken from India to Amsterdam where there is a layover and then to Munich, is the immigration done at Amsterdam or at Munich? Since most Schengen flights are treated similar to domestic flights.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Immigration and visas are handled at the level of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), **not** the EU. The Schengen Area covers most of the EU, but some EU countries are not in Schengen (such as Ireland, Romania, Bulgaria...), while some non-EU countries are in Schengen (such as Switzerland, Norway...).

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Schengen_Area_(Lablled_Map).png)

- Dark blue = EU + Schengen
- Green and yellow = EU, not Schengen (UK in transition period)
- Purple = Schengen, not EU
- Light blue = not EU, "*de facto*" Schengen

A flight **within Schengen** (not within the EU) is indeed treated like a domestic flight for immigration purposes, so passport control will happen at the **first point in the Schengen Area** (Amsterdam in your example, since both Amsterdam and Munich are in the Schengen Area).

Note that this applies only to immigration (passport/visa control). Customs checks still happen at the final airport (in most cases).

Also note that in some cases (e.g. due to the migrant crisis) there may be additional checks even within the Schengen Area. These are supposed to be temporary.

Comment: What are the light blue dots in Italy as well as France? And the gray one between France and Spain?

Comment: @JosephP. Those are San Marino, Monaco and Vatican, which are treated as part of the Schengen Zone, and Andorra, which is not (so if you want to visit Andorra, you need a multiple entry Schengen visa as opposed to a single entry).

Comment: The map contains a small error: Luxemburg is also member both of the EU and the Schengen area (in fact, the village that gave the Schengen treaty its name is in Luxemburg)

Comment: @DjClayworth ah, my fault, the original legend for green was “Common Travel Area” and I changed that to me more relevant to the context of the answer. However, even though the UK is formally out of the EU, for all practical purposes it’s still part of it, for now.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez, Switzerland is purple (-ish), so it is indeed "full" Schengen, like Iceland and Norway. Only the 3 micro-states Monaco, San Marino and Vatican are light blue and "_de facto_". Switzerland could not be "_de facto_" since it is possible to arrive there from outside the Schengen Area (by air), while this is nearly impossible for Vatican and San Marino. Not sure how Monaco handles arrivals/departures by sea, though.

Comment: @jcaron German Wikipedia says that French authorities are conducting the border formalities at the Monaco harbour.

Comment: @jcaron I see it now. It looked light blue on my phone.

Comment: The map shows the Republic of Ireland in green, not just the UK.  Should the Republic of Ireland be a different color?

Comment: @Panzercrisis No, Ireland is EU, but not Schengen, which is what the green color is for. It's the UK that will change color once it exits the transition period, in which case it will be neither EU nor Schengen.

Comment: @Panzercrisis The original map's legend says that green is "Common Travel Area". At the moment it is practically synonymous with "EU not Schengen" (until the end of the Brexit transition period). At the end of the transition period the UK should probably turn grey, neither EU nor Schengen, I guess.

Comment: @reirab Then what is the difference between green and yellow on this map? The legend indicates they have the same meaning, so I suppose it could be a mere  design choice. (That would be odd.) I wrongly inferred that the UK was green to indicate "EU, not Schengen, and leaving," in which case Ireland would be yellow.

Comment: On the original map (I simplified the legend here to just highlight the point I was trying to make), yellow is "EU, will join Schengen as soon as possible". Green used to be "EU, permanent exemption", though with Brexit of course things are a little different (ahem) now.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive Yeah, like jcaron said, yellow is (at least in theory) future Schengen states, which have joined the EU relatively recently.